# How to view Street View for certain date?

Tags: google-maps, street-view

I was checking out [this answer showing how the Colorado DOT dealt with mile-marker theft issue](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/a/23241/665).

You can see that user [Sparr](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/users/6575/sparr) used Street View images of the spot from different dates to answer the question.

How is that done?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

First enter Street View mode in desktop Google Maps. Notice the overlay in the upper-right corner with the address and Street View date, and next to the date is a clock-cycle icon.

Click that icon to pick a different date.

See [Go back in time with Street View](http://google-latlong.blogspot.com/2014/04/go-back-in-time-with-street-view.html) in the Google Maps blog for details and screen shots.

Comment: That was easy! I thought I was going to have to hack around with the URL.

Comment: That feature was added in April, 2014. http://google-latlong.blogspot.com/2014/04/go-back-in-time-with-street-view.html

Comment: Thanks Jerry101, never noticed before that button. For some reason it shows up in Chrome but not in FF.

Comment: @psxls that's odd. I'm seeing the time button in both FF and Chrome on MacOS. Is it the same location in both browsers? Some locations might not have SV history available. Or maybe the feature depends on a browser plug-in.

Comment: To make it even more strange, I just realized that the exact same URL in FF and in Chrome are showing me different menus in Google Maps. Take for example this URL https://www.google.com/maps/@37.9437673,23.6852958,3a,75y,89.87h,90t/data=!3m6!1e1!3m4!1sETKLQ6C_i8Ll-w1nXkTA3g!2e0!7i13312!8i6656

Comment: In Chrome it is fine. In FF the upper left control is different without historic imagery. But (!) when I switch the same URL in FF, to my local google.gr/maps instead of google.com/maps then it works fine...